# How do I play Star Wars: Trench Run?

Tags: star-wars-trench-run

I played [*Star Wars: Trench Run*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Trench_Run) a few years back and enjoyed it immensely. It's a browser game that runs on Unity Web Player, which has since been deprecated both by Unity and by many web browsers which now don't support NPAPI plugins. However, the game can still be accessed on certain places on the Internet, and Internet Explorer is capable of running old, deprecated plugins. (Thanks iexplore, it's the only thing you're good for these days.)

However, when I try to run the game, nothing works. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Thanks.

Update: Looks like it's trying to download unityplayer2.x.x-win32. Does anyone know where I can download this and have it work? Thanks.